# Return private static member of a class

Tags: c++, static-members, private-members

I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/UTCPP.pdf) example on the net that leads me on the following code:

EquipmentCollection.h (header file)

```
#ifndef EQUIMENTCOLLECTION_H_
#define EQUIMENTCOLLECTION_H_

#include "Equipment.h"
#include <vector>

class EquipmentCollection : public Equipment {
public:
    static void add( Equipment* );
    static vector<Equipment*>& get();
    ~EquipmentCollection();
private:
    static vector<Equipment*>* equipmentList;
};

#endif /* EQUIMENTCOLLECTION_H_ */
```

EquipmentCollection.cpp ( source file )

```
#include "EquipmentCollection.h"

void EquipmentCollection::add( Equipment* equipment ) {
    if( equipmentList == NULL ) {
        equipmentList = new vector<Equipment*>();
    }

    equipmentList->push_back( equipment );
}

vector<Equipment*>& EquipmentCollection::get() {
    return *equipmentList;
}

EquipmentCollection::~EquipmentCollection() {
    delete( equipmentList );
}
```

My error is `return *equipmentList;` on the source file which gives me `undefined reference to "EquipmentCollection::equipmentList"` error. I don't know why it gives me that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not initialized your static member. You should add in your CPP file, the following code:

```
vector<Equipment*>* EquipmentCollection::equipmentList = nullptr;
```

Also your code has other problems:

- You don't create any instance of `EquipmentCollection`, so your destructor will never be called and equipment will never be freed.
- `EquipmentCollection::get` will have an [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if no `::add` was called before, because of (8.3.2/4 "References"):

> Note: in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined
>   program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to
>   bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer,
>   which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: About the other problems. If I create the instance on the `main()` method that will be resolve right?

And for the second issue. I'm learning Unit Testing to avoid that. That is what this example for.

Am I right?

Comment: @user2785929: creating an instance of a class, to later only use its static functions and only to de-initialize static member sounds a bit like an anti-pattern to me. About unit tests, unit tests can test your code. They can't eliminate undefined behavior as it is defined in language official standard.

Comment: I see your point. Thank you for guiding me. I'm really new to c++

Comment: You could also mention that simply storing the vector by value will get rid of all the problems.